# allow OS shutdown to timeout without failing Packer build

Tags: vagrant, packer

I have an OS which doesn't shut down properly when I run it in one particular hypervisor (KVM) even though it works on all other hypervisors. Instead, what it does is sync all data to disk and then hang indefinitely with the message `"Hit any button to reboot"` until you issue a hard shutdown from the hypervisor.

I'm trying to automate a no-touch installation of this OS from an `.iso` file into a `.box` file using Packer. However, the Packer run fails every time because it hits the `shutdown_timeout` (from the QEMU builder) while the OS is hung waiting for input. I'm looking for a workaround -- it seems like either of the following could work (and maybe there are other ways), but I can't figure out any way to do them! Some ideas I've searched for were:

- tell Packer to do a hard shutdown after a certain amount of time
- tell Packer that hitting this timeout isn't an error and it should just do a hard shutdown and continue with the provisioner steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon rereading the docs, I found the answer:

> `shutdown_command` (string) - The command to use to gracefully shut down the machine once all the provisioning is done. **By default this is an empty string, which tells Packer to just forcefully shut down the machine.**

D'oh!